# How can i display a image in codeigniter outside root directory

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i display a image from outside the document root. To be precise

```
/ <-- root directory
/public_html/ <-- document root 
/application/upload/img <-- here is the source of image
```

I made in codeigniter and it works but has a big delay if i try to load multiple times. I this it is in codeigniter a helper function to help me and boost my time to load the file.

I show the code what i have write:

This is in controller:

```
public function img($img_name){
    $t = $this->getupload->Get($img_name); // here is taked from DB using MODEL
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Content-type: {$t[0]['file_type']}"); // Take the file type (eg: images/jpg) from DB
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
    flush();
    readfile($t[0]['full_path']); // here take the imgfile from DB
}
```

Comment: Why not just move the file to the public directory? Currently your app is having to copy the image into memory and then spit it out. It'd be way faster to just have your http server do what its built for.

Comment: @castis The only reason I can think of to do this is if the image was user submitted (which it appears to be since the folder name is `.../upload/...`) since it is typically best practice to not allow user uploaded stuff into the webroot.

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn You are right, i want to make a secure upload and if any "hacker" tries to break the script to not have any access to the file what has been uploaded.

Comment: Yeah, I'd have it check the file to make sure its only of a specified set of image types prior to upload or hand-validate them and move them over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you will want your server to work, and not the code.

You should configure your apache or nginx to fetch the data from that path.

in apache htaccess you could try:

```
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ /var/www/application/upload/img/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

I'm not sure it will work, but this is an idea.

in nginx you can check something like this:

```
location /uploads/* {
    try_files /var/www/application/upload/img/$query_string;
}
```

again I'm not sure it will work, as I'm not a servers master,
but if this is what you would like to accomplish I would suggest checking that.

Comment: If i do this i can directly access the files ... if you know any why to make accesibles just from localhost (php) and not directly accesed.

Comment: So if it is for security, so you must usw PHP AS you written in the post, you can use caching to reduce usage